# Rails: I wish my counter_cache to don't touch updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rails-activerecord

I have a `Contact` model that `belongs_to` `User` and has `:counter_cache` true.

Whenever `User` has a new `Contact`, Rails updates the `User.contacts_count` column, but it also updates the `User` `expired_at` timestamp.

I didn't wish this to happen because of my caching strategy, where I do NOT need the cache to expire whenever a User gets a new contact.

Any way to do this other then implementing a manual counter cache ?

Comment: Could you provide more detail as to which tables these columns are on and what methods are called on save?

Comment: By default, counter_cache's methods will do direct SQL updates without touching the `updated_at` column. Are you using `touch: true` on `belongs_to :user`?